# Remove NAs from nested dictionary (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary called 'trial'. Inside it, there are keys called 'data' that contain a list of svg strings and 'measurements' that contain a list of integers.

Currently, if a measurement is less than 50, then I set the corresponding data to 'NA'. However, rather than set it to NA, I hope to remove it entirely from the list. Does anyone have advice?

Many thanks in advance!

```
    // extract trial data
    trial.data = _.map(trial.data, 'svg');

    // extract trial measurements
    trial.measurements = _.map(trial.measures, function(n, i) {
        return n['measurements']
    });

    // if a measurement is less than 50 inches, then set the data to 'NA'
    $.each(trial.measurements, function(n,len) {
      if (len < 50) {
        trial.data[n] = 'NA'; 
      }
    });
```

Comment: are you using jquery and underscore for this? if so, if you tag your question with these tags then you're more likely to get experts in that field looking at this question

Comment: Why use that `$.each` loop at all then? If it's never assigned, you don't have to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)?

`delete trial.data[n]`;

Or you could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const trial = {
  measures: Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({ measurement: Math.random() * 100 }))
}


document.getElementById('original').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(trial, null, 2);

const filtered = trial.measures.filter(x => x.measurement >= 50);

document.getElementById('filtered').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filtered, null, 2);
```

```css
div {
  display: flex
}

div > * {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

#original::before {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: 'original'
}

#filtered::before {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: 'filtered'
}
```

```html
<div>
  <pre id="original"></pre>
  <pre id="filtered"></pre>
</div>
```